# Can't manipulate files in ubuntu

Tags: text-editor

I have a Problem on my Ubuntu machine.  When I try to open some file in an editor like nano, vi or `sudo gedit`, nothing shows up, but `nano ~/.bashrc` works fine without any problem.

I have two user accounts on my Ubuntu system, and it's the same problem with the other user account.

Comment: Why you tagged this question as it would be about Ubuntu One?

Comment: Which system version are you using? Why `sudo gedit`?

Comment: I dont know exactly where to ask my question :(

Comment: Ubuntu One is a Dropbox-like service... Tag it with the Ubuntu version you're using!

Comment: Can you say me which files are you trying to edit?

Comment: i.e **nano etc/apt/sources.list** or **nano conf/hadoop-env.sh**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to open the files with commands like this:

```
nano etc/apt/sources.list
nano conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

In the first, you forget to add the root folder! Just add a slash before the rest of the file path:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the second, you need to add the Hadoop path:

```
nano $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

Also, you'll probably need to open them as root user, so add sudo before all the command (just like with gedit!):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo nano $HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh
```

Comment: I did it but no changes :(

Comment: Modified! Now you should be able to do what you want!

Comment: Wow...good catch @espectalll123. I made the assumption that he was coming from a relative path and knew what he was opening. (I just typed the /etc out of habit more than anything.)

Answer (score 0):

vi function in **Ubuntu** is different, you can install **vim-nox** or **vim** package
So after that you can try it for the same file

use following command

```
sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

or

```
 sudo apt-get install vim
```

Comment: That's not what's he asking... I think.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I thin my problem is from another thing. if i run **nano etc/apt/sources.list** it works fine. The folder the the file are in them have a lock

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are having an issue manipulating files is that you must have the appropriate level permissions in order to manipulate those files.

So, for example, if you want to manipulate /etc/apt/sources.list, that requires that you use sudo to temporarily elevate your permissions so you can edit the file. On your current user account, try:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you are already part of the sudo group, then you will be asked for your password. Once you type in your password, your privileges will be temporarily escalated so you can edit the file and save it.

If you are not part of the sudo group, another user on the system who has sudo access can add you by doing:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo your-user-name
```

Learn more about Linux permissions here: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: thank you for your answer. for this command **sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list** works fine but for this one **sudo nano conf/hadoop-env.sh** the problem remain

Comment: For the second command, read what I answered!

Comment: I did it but no changes in result :(